# Importing GUI's from glade into code::blocks

Tags: c++, xml, user-interface, codeblocks, glade

I want to import a test GUI I made in glade into a project in `code::blocks`. 
I followed a guide to import it as an xml into the project, whether that works or not, I bumped into a problem, `code::blocks` can't find the header file `<glade/glade.h>`, which is located at `/usr/include/libglade-2.0/glade/glade.h`.

If I set the include path to that absolute path, I get the same problem with other files which `glade.h` needs to include.

Do I need to export glade into the environment variable, if so how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to add `/usr/include/libglade-2.0` into your list of include directories; this is an option in Code::Blocks somewhere.

You then write `#include <glade/glade.h>`.

Comment: I tried adding that in an environmental variable in code::blocks under settings->environment, and under project->build options, I added glade = /usr/include/libglade-2.0 under custom variables there. still doesn't work.

Comment: @inifus: Neither of those things are what I told you to do.

Comment: I got it to work. I misunderstood you, sorry. but thanx for the help :) I added /usr/include/libglade-2.0 in the search directories for compiler and linker. now it finds the header files :)

Comment: @inifus: Hurray! BTW - just do it for compiler.

Comment: @inifus: Go ahead and _accept_ the answer if you're happy with it.